# 3D Scatter chart scrolling if I scroll the scrollbar

Tags: angularjs, charts, highcharts, scatter, highcharts-ng

I am rendering Highcharts 3D scatter graph and enabled scrolling as follows

```
xAxis: {
  categories: xlist,
  min: 0,
  max: 4,
  scrollbar: {
    enabled: true
  },
}
```

Also having chart scrolling with below code

```
$(chart.container).on('mousedown.hc touchstart.hc', function (eStart) {
                eStart = chart.pointer.normalize(eStart);

                var posX = eStart.chartX,
                posY = eStart.chartY,
                alpha = chart.options.chart.options3d.alpha,
                beta = chart.options.chart.options3d.beta,
                newAlpha,
                newBeta,
                    sensitivity = 5; // lower is more sensitive

                    $(document).on({
                        'mousemove.hc touchmove.hc': function (e) {

                        e = chart.pointer.normalize(e);
                        newBeta = beta + (posX - e.chartX) / sensitivity;
                        chart.options.chart.options3d.beta = newBeta;


                        newAlpha = alpha + (e.chartY - posY) / sensitivity;
                        chart.options.chart.options3d.alpha = newAlpha;

                        chart.redraw(false);
                    },
                    'mouseup touchend': function () {
                        $(document).off('.hc');
                    }
                });
                });
```

If I scroll through scrollbar then the chart also moves. Is there any way to avoid chart scrolling if I scroll the scrollbar and if I take mouse on chart then the chart should move.

Comment: I moved your example to jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1nhv6075/) and I still don't quite understand what do you want to change in current behavior of scrollbar. What do you mean by saying "chart moves"? Rotating or/and changing extremes? Please provide some screenshots and more detailed explanation.

Comment: xAxis scrolling should change on xAxis labels and should not move the chart angle.

Comment: It works this way if you comment out the last block of code: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/q0nb2nur/

Comment: Yes. But I want that code to scroll 3dScatter chart and scrollbar to move the axis points.

Comment: Here's an example with scatter 3d: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/q0nb2nur/ What should be changed in it?

Comment: If you want to look at the chart from zAxis perspective. How can you move the chart.?

Comment: Do you want to use scrollbar to zoom in/out on the chart or to change the extremes of the z axis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a hack and updated the above function as below, where I have restricted the chart rotation with  **if(e.target.classList.length == 0)** when we use scrollbar.

```
$(chart.container).on('mousedown.hc touchstart.hc', function (eStart) {
            eStart = chart.pointer.normalize(eStart);

            var posX = eStart.chartX,
            posY = eStart.chartY,
            alpha = chart.options.chart.options3d.alpha,
            beta = chart.options.chart.options3d.beta,
            newAlpha,
            newBeta,
                sensitivity = 5; // lower is more sensitive

                $(document).on({
                    'mousemove.hc touchmove.hc': function (e) {
                  if (e.target.classList.length == 0) {
                    e = chart.pointer.normalize(e);
                    newBeta = beta + (posX - e.chartX) / sensitivity;
                    chart.options.chart.options3d.beta = newBeta;


                    newAlpha = alpha + (e.chartY - posY) / sensitivity;
                    chart.options.chart.options3d.alpha = newAlpha;

                    chart.redraw(false);
                  }
                },
                'mouseup touchend': function () {
                    $(document).off('.hc');
                }
            });
            });
```